# Parse Error: There was a problem parsing the package

Tags: android, apk

I try to resolve this error from various methods in my Hello World App.These are;
-Go to Security-->Unknown sources.
-Go to About phone-->Build number.
-Update my manifest file whose picture is given below.
-Test app both on phone Y625 Huawei and on tablet T1-701u tab.
-Reboot android phone and android studio (version 3.4.1).
-Transfer apk file via data cable or airmove software.

But none of them works to solve the issue.

I develop my Hello World. Firstly i faced insufficient heap size error issue which has solved on the temporary basis. After build up my app, Parsing the package issue has emerged.

```
Manifest File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hw04">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

package com.example.hw04;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Parse Error

There was a problem parsing the package enter code here

Comment: If you install the .apk via ADB, I think it gives you a little more information why it can't parse the package.

Comment: Thank you Sir.A long process via ADB has finally run my.apk file but i still don't know why Parse error was being created. Another thing, i am facing the Gradle sync issue. Though i increase heap size but it is a temporary solution. Please guide me about permanent solution. Thank you Sir once again.